# how to set a variable as a list in packer for ansible?

Tags: list, ansible, packer

When trying to pass a var that is normally a list in ansible, I cannot do this in packer.

```
  provisioner "ansible" {
    playbook_file = "./ansible/houdini_module.yaml"
    extra_arguments = [
      "-vv",
      "--extra-vars",
      "houdini_major_version_list=[19.0]",
    ]
  }
```

In my playbook if I test the length of houdini_major_version_list with `{{ houdini_major_version_list|length }}` it says the length is 6, when it should be 1.

What is the correct way to pass a list using --extra-vars in packer?

Comment: Try using it like `{{ var.split()}}`, untested.

Comment: That would require changing the module for packer use only which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is instructive in explaining why the type is incorrect as a variable input to Ansible through the CLI. The update to the Packer HCL2 template to satisfy this requirement and solve your problem would be:

```
provisioner "ansible" {
  playbook_file = "${path.root}/ansible/playbook.yaml"
  extra_arguments = [
    "-vv",
    "--extra-vars",
    jsonencode({ "houdini_major_version_list" = ["19.0"] }),
  ]
}
```

setting the env var `PACKER_LOG=1` we see that this executes:

```
ansible-playbook ... -vv --extra-vars {"houdini_major_version_list":["19.0"]} ... /path/to/playbook.yaml
```

This demonstrates the interfacing between Packer and the Ansible provisioner is now correct for passing a `list` type variable.

Note that `jsonencode({ "houdini_major_version_list" = [19.0]` results in `{"houdini_major_version_list":[19]}` because the float automatically drops the `.0`.

Comment: That is exactly what was needed and worked flawlessly.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the extra variable `-e, --extra-vars` in [key=value format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#key-value-format) is always a string. Given the variable below, declared anywhere in a code,

```yaml
l: [19.0]
```

the result of the task below is as expected

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          l|type_debug: {{ l|type_debug }}
          l|length: {{ l|length }}
          l.0|type_debug: {{ l.0|type_debug }}
          l.0: {{ l.0 }}
```

```yaml
  msg: |-
    l|type_debug: list
    l|length: 1
    l.0|type_debug: float
    l.0: 19.0
```

---

But, when you declare this variable at the command line in the `k=v` format the type is a string and the length of this string is 6

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e l=[19.0]
...
  msg: |-
    l|type_debug: str
    l|length: 6
    l.0|type_debug: str
    l.0: [
```

---

To fix this, use [JSON string format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#json-string-format)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml -e '{"l": [19.0]}'
...
  msg: |-
    l|type_debug: list
    l|length: 1
    l.0|type_debug: float
    l.0: 19.0
```

The YAML format gives the same result

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "l: [19.0]"
```

---

Optionally, put the variable into a [JSON or YAML file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#vars-from-a-json-or-yaml-file). It's practical when declaring more variables. For example

```yaml
shell> cat some_file.yml
l: [19.0]
k: [20.0]
```

would give

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook2.yml -e "@some_file.yml"
...
  msg: |-
    l.0: 19.0
    k.0: 20.0
```

---

Convert the variable on you own if you're not able to change the format of the command. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l_local: "{{ l.split('=')|last|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          l_local|type_debug: {{ l_local|type_debug }}
          l_local|length: {{ l_local|length }}
          l_local.0|type_debug: {{ l_local.0|type_debug }}
          l_local.0: {{ l_local.0 }}
```

Then, the command gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "l=[19.0]"
...
  msg: |-
    l_local|type_debug: list
    l_local|length: 1
    l_local.0|type_debug: float
    l_local.0: 19.0
```

You can't override the extra variable, i.e `l` in this case, because the `extra vars` is the [highest precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

Comment: This well addresses the Ansible part of the root cause, but not the Packer. The HCL2 would need to be amended as `extra_arguments = [..., jsonencode({"houdini_major_version_list"=[19.0]})]` to satisfy the Ansible CLI formatting requirements you describe in the answer.

Comment: Convert the value on your own. I added an example.